# Remove Dell Openmanage from Windows 2008

Tags: dell, uninstall

I have installed Dell Openmanage Server Agent 4.2.2 on Windows Server 2008. I need the newer version, so I need to install this version first.
However, outside some registry references pointing to sources that aren't there, there is little or no trace of it being installed. For example, no trace of the program files or an entry in Prgrams And Features. Still, installing a newer version keeps coming up with an older version that needs to be removed first.
When I try to install version 4.2.2 to repair and eventually remove it, it gives an error:

Dell Openmanage Server Agent - Error

An error was encountered while testing machine type. Failure
openingen required handle to .DLL. Dell Openmanage Server Agent
cannot continue the installation.
Setup will exit now.

I haven't found anything using different parts of the error messages as search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a tool called OMClean which should help you remove all of the assorted "extras" from the uninstall process.  I'm pretty sure its part of the Openmanage installation cd.

Comment: I found it. When I run it, it seems to work but afterwards nothing changed, at least not effectively.

Comment: OMclean logfiles gives no error, says everything is sets out to remove, is removed.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the originally installed version, to get a "clean" install, then uninstalling?  Is it possible the original installation didn't go properly?  Can you confirm you have installed any prerequisites?

Comment: Re-installing the original (v4.2.2) immediately gives the error I mentioned, which points to a dll that is only identified as .DLL.
Newer versions have uninstalling it as a prerequisite.
Looking through the registery hasn't helped any.

Comment: Check the Dell OM forums.  What you're seeing is definitely odd but the Dell people might have see this before.

Comment: I will do that. Sorry for the delay, lately I seem to get involved in projects that change priority faster than I change my mind.

Comment: I seem to have a nose for problems that dissappear for reasons external to them. The server has been replaced -> problem gone.
Thanks for the comments.